# QTableWidget insertRow() inserting empty rows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

what I'm missing when populating table rows to avoid adding empty rows. For example if the items inserted are two, there is additional one empty row added at the top and so on:

```
def search_watchlist_category(self) -> None:
    """ Get details watchlist based on the search word matches
    :return None
    """
    search_word = ErrorMessaging.remove_spaces(self.searchText.text())

    if search_word == '':
        self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setRowCount(0)
        self.watchlistButton.setText("Watchlist")
        self.watchlistButton.setStyleSheet('color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #312624; border: 0px')

    else:
        search_query = search_word.split(' ')[0]

        response = utils.search_watchlists(search_query)
        self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setRowCount(0)

        matched_results = response['watchlist_details']
        num_rows = len(matched_results)

        self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setRowCount(num_rows)

        for watchlist_category in response['watchlist_details']:
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setShowGrid(False)
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(
                'background-color: transparent;')
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
                QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)

            checkbox_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('')
            checkbox_item.setFlags(checkbox_item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                                   QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
            checkbox_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            checkbox_item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('#FFFFFF'))

            watchlist_targets = utils.get_persons_of_interest_in_category(watchlist_category.id)

            target_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(len(watchlist_targets)))
            target_item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('#FFFFFF'))

            watchlist_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f"{watchlist_category.name}")
            watchlist_item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('#FFFFFF'))

            watchlist_item.setData(Qt.UserRole, watchlist_category.id)
            watchlist_item.setData(Qt.UserRole + 1, watchlist_category.date_created)
            watchlist_item.setData(Qt.UserRole + 2, watchlist_category.description)
            watchlist_item.setData(Qt.UserRole + 3, watchlist_category.color)

            row_position = self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.rowCount()
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.insertRow(row_position)
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setItem(row_position - 1, 0, checkbox_item)
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setItem(row_position - 1, 1, watchlist_item)
            self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setItem(row_position - 1, 2, target_item)

            self.watchlistButton.setText("Watchlist(" + str(num_rows) + ")")
```

Comment: There is a line `self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setRowCount(num_rows)` that sets the number of rows to match the number of results. So if you have 2 items, before entering the loop `for watchlist_category in response['watchlist_details']:`, row count is already 2. Then, you keep adding rows by `self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.insertRow(row_position)` - these rows are actually populated.

Comment: @Thomenson thanks for the comment. If I remove the line `self.watchlist_results.watchlistsTable.setRowCount(num_rows)`; if the items are two it inserts one and an empty row at the end of the table and so on. How best can i do this?

Comment: You insert a row at the end using `...insertRow(row_position)` but then immediately update the data in the previous row using `...setItem(row_position - 1, ...`.

Comment: So with that line removed, your `rowCount` in the first iteration is equal to `0`. You are trying then to insert the data to the row `-1`. Try to remove subtracting `1` from `row_position`.

Comment: @Thomenson Thanks removing subtracting `1` worked

Comment: Hi @Thomenson Is there away I can split the data and populate 3 tables at ago. Each table to have 10 rows of data. Or if there is any way I can split a `QTableWidget`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly - you can avoid inserting row over and over again and do this once for all rows (ie. if you have ten items, just `setRowCount` to 10 and then refer to appropriate row in each iteration). However, if you would like to push all the data in one shot (so to avoid the loop), nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: @Thomenson I have edited the question and attached the screenshot of what I wan't to achieve. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @B.Obilo 1) have you solved your original problem? If so, then post a reply or delete your post. 2) You should not add additional questions but create a new post. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved a similar issue to the one you posted.

In my case, a new row was supposed to be added when a certain button was clicked. However, each time I clicked the button, an additional empty row was added at the end of the table.

I solved the problem by **taking** the *insertRow()* **out** from the *for* loop.